# mask edges are not continuous - how to solve

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mask

my ML model is producing a binary mask (separate file) for each object.

The objects are not "filled out" (that is, there are very often "holes" inside the objects).

The issue is that when the "holes" are too close to the edge, the object edges are not continuous, and therefore filling up the holes becomes harder.

Here are two examples:

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

My code for filling the holes is not working in these cases:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

mask = np.array(Image.open('example1.png'))
_, mask_binary = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(mask_binary, [contour], 0, 255, -1)
plt.imshow(mask_binary, cmap='gray')
```

I imagine there are "morphological" ways to "close" such open spaces, but I did not figure out how. 
**Any suggestions?** 
If there is a different way to resolve my issue (that will not necessitate redoing the ML model...) I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: Have you tried [`Closing`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)?

Comment: adding this code: `kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)` 
`mask_binary = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)` before the cv2.findContours did not help.

Comment: This is a really difficult thing to solve. Can’t you train the model to produce solid regions?

Comment: Have you tried erosion and dilation with different kernel size and iteration number? e.g. `dilation = cv2.dilate(mask_binary ,kernel9 ,iterations = 3)` then `erosion = cv2.erode(dilation ,kernel3 ,iterations = 1)`  Edit: I made a mistake, changed the order

Comment: tried now with different amounts of iterations. It solves the issue to some extent, but actually makes worse other cases (which do not have the edges problem). The plan is to have the code run autonomously. So not sure if this solution is general enough

Comment: you can check which case has edge problem by number of contours. probably images with edge problem have more contours than others. do the closing only with them. this is the biggest problem of classic image processing that no code is working fine for all cases.